# WPF - ScrollViewer content overflowing

Tags: .net, wpf

I have a WPF control with this basic structure:

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="_Scroll" Grid.Row="4" Grid.RowSpan="20" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" CanContentScroll="True" >
        <StackPanel x:Name="_Panel" />
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Some `Grid` items are added to _Panel later, during execution, thus generating a list of items vertically aligned. It all works properly when the scrollbar isn't visible, but when I actually *need* to scroll the content, the StackPanel overflows and I end up seeing part of the StackPanel's content *above* the ScrollViewer. Any idea as to what could be causing this issue? If you need more details, let me know and I'll edit the question appropriately.

**EDIT**: [Added an image explaining the issue better](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8X08.png): above is what the control looks like before beginning to scroll, below is the issue with the items overflowing over the ScrollViewer. As for the code, there's nothing particular about the insertion of items in the panel, it's basically among the lines of:

```
Dim nRow As New Grid
' Insertion of subcontrols within nRow
_Panel.Children.Add(nRow)
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal code example sufficient to reproduce the issue.

Comment: A screenshot of what you are seeing would also be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

this is because the amount of items added later in your stackpanel does not update the height of the scroll bar, which is external to it, and refers only to the original size of the stackpanel
you can solve as folowing:

[Edit] give your stackpanel a relative or absolute size for the scroll to be displayed.

something like that:

```
<Grid Name="GridContent" Height="XXX" >
    <StackPanel Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=GridContent}"
                Orientation="Vertical" 
                ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
                ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">

    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I tried this solution, but now it doesn't show the scrollbar anymore, not even if I set VerticalScrollBarVisibility as Visible.

Comment: The StackPanel, Grid, Canvas, and other containers have infinite size, you can give them a relative or absolute size, so your scrollviewer will be displayed, I have no other information to help you, if you update the question with more information would be easier

Comment: Agreed, ScrollViewers will have odd behavior when inserted into a container with a non-determinate size. Even when everything looks okay in the mark-up.

Comment: @CarloPiras This is why you should add controls via an ItemsControl and a DataTemplate. If you don’t cooperate with WPF, it won’t cooperate with you.